# Magento 2 Create button on order section in Admin Panel

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GflWM.png)

I am very new to magento 2. I want to create a button on the admin's sales panel e.g. change State. It's functionality will be similar to the hold or unhold button that if i click the button, the order status will be changed to myState. However, i get to the point that confuse me is how i can customize my own function of the button.

I created the button like this on View.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmBBc.png)

However, there is a line with getChangeStateUrl()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqetz.png)

i do not know what is the file located on getUrl("sales/*/change_state") because it seems the file that i need to customize.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88949 and add my function on the View.php. Since e.g. Mage::getModel is not worked on magento 2 so I used $objectManager to change the state and status of the order. However, I do not get to the point of the getUrl so i return to the same page like this.

return $this->getUrl('sales/order/view');